# Citroen C4 screen wash pump location

Tags: citroen, windshield-washer, citroen-c4

Where might that be located on a c4 2005 (Petrol). I can't seam to locate it, nothing specific in the handbook and nothing on the Interwebs. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Upgrade it to an answer. Given it's the exact same pump as the C4 Picasso, and your answer applies for the Picasso it is very safe to assume you're correct. I've decided to order the pump online and proceed under the assumptions in your comment. On my part I'll be sure to update either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, it should be located behind the bumper cover on the right side of the vehicle (from driver's perspective). Follow the refill tube for the washer reservoir. It's mounted on the bottom of the reservoir. You'll have to remove the bumper cover to gain access to it. This, of course, is all conjecture on my part, because I'm only seeing newer C4 versions (like 2015 and newer), but this is where it's located on the newer models. I'd suggest it's the same for the older ones.